# jQuery in Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin and in it I use jQuery, but it is not working.
My code is below :
script.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        $("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");    
    }

    else {
        $("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }

  });

  $("#toTop").click(function() {
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);

  });

});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with jQuery and php together, you should use jQuery $no.conflict().
your code will look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");    
    }

    else {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }

  });

  jQuery("#toTop").click(function() {
    jQuery("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is reserved in WordPress for the Prototype library, so use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");    
    }

    else {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }

  });

  jQuery("#toTop").click(function() {
    jQuery("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` like this:--

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

    $("#toTop").click(function() {

        $("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);

    });
});
```

Hope it may work.